# Synonym request for [computer-vision] and [image-processing]

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

The tags [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) (1,393 questions tagged, 450 followers):

> Computer vision enables images, or sequences of images, to be processed by a computer using an algorithm. The aim of the algorithm is to extract information from the image. Sometimes this information produces an updated image or sometimes other measurements. An example of an updated image is to ...

and [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) (7,338 questions tagged, 858 followers)

> Algorithms which extract and manipulate information from digital images.

should be synonyms.

As there are more questions and more followers to [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) this could be the new master. On the other hand [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) has a better tag wiki and it is already master to [machine-vision](/questions/tagged/machine-vision). A hard decision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree. [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) is a broader field, [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) is a pretty specific part of that.

Bluring, Sharpening, Mapping to different colors are all part of image-processing and can have the desired result of making the image look different/better/worse/...

Computer vision, on the other hand is about *extracting non-image information* from an image. For example if I have an image of several objects, I want to know how many cans of cola it shows. It often uses techniques from general image processing, however.